# Generating my own Windows DbgHelp MiniDump. I don't need to distribute PDB files, do I?

Tags: winapi, pdb-files, dbghelp

I need to double  check my understanding of DbgHelp and crash dumps.

To cope with some crashes my Windows application has encountered in the field, I've written an UnhandledExceptionFilter that uses the MiniDumpWriteDump function (from DbgHelp.dll) to write out a .DMP file.  It seems to work well and it appears I can see the full crash info even if the client does not have the PDBs when the crash occcurs (as long as I have them when I open the dump file)

I am just hoping for a confirmation.  Is there any need for me to distribute the PDBs?  Is there some information that I might fail to get in the DMP file from a client crash if I were not to distribute them?

Comment: you not need distribute pdb files. they not used when dump created. it used only when you open dump in debugger, for convert virtual addresses to symbols names

Comment: *Is there some information that I might fail to get in the DMP file from a client crash if I were not to distribute them* - no, pdb not used in here. you nothing lost.

Comment: From [Minidump Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/minidump-files): *"To **read** a minidump file, you must have the binaries and symbol files available for the debugger."* To write a minidump, you don't need symbol information (unless your user-supplied callbacks make use of symbol information).

Comment: @IInspectable:  Yeah, I did see that.  That's what I figured. I just wasn't sure and didn't want something to come back to haunt me.  I think it would be helpful if they would be more explicit and add your second sentence into the documentation.